# Has anyone got BadgeCount working with BottomNavigationBarXF

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm using a third-party plugin called [BottomNavigationBarXF](https://github.com/thrive-now/BottomNavigationBarXF) which display tabs at the bottom edge of the screen on Android. I got the tabs working but whenever I set the BadgeCount (as per their sample), I get following exception:

Position 11:110. Cannot assign property "BadgeCount": Property does not exists, or is not assignable, or mismatching type between value and property

Answer (score 0):

If not mistaken , you use ThriveGmbH.BottomNavigationBar.EXT version 1.0.2 but the sample used latest version 1.0.6 in nuget (ThriveGmbH.BottomNavigationBar.LATEST). The order version 1.0.2 might don't have the badgecount parameter. I uninstall 1.02 version and install 1.06 version and the badgecount is working.